# Flutter: Carrying over data from one file to another

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two files...Workout.dart and Submit.dart. In Workout.dart I have variables: name, sets, rep, pmg, and smg. The use will input things for the variables and then once they click submit, a new page will open displaying the data. However, I don't know how to carry over that data. I'm new to Flutter and Dart, Please help!

**Workout.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gyminprogress/Submit.dart';

class This extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
   Workout createState() => Workout();
}

class Workout extends State<This> {
  String name , sets , rep , pmg , smg ;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Workouts'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Exercise Name'
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    name = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Primary Muscle Group'
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    pmg = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Secondary Muscle Group'
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    smg = value;
                  });
                },
              ),SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Reps'
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    rep = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Sets'
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    sets = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.cyan[200],
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 80.0,
                      vertical: 20.0
                      ,),
                      child: Text('Submit',style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w200
                      ),) , 
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Submit ( 

                        )),
                        );
                        },
                    ),
                  ]
                ),]),)
              )
            ]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
    }
  }
```

**Submit.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gyminprogress/Workout.dart';

class Submit extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
   Enter createState() => Enter();
}

class Enter extends State<Submit> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Workouts'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Exercise Name : ${Workout.name}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),),
              Text('Primary Muscle Group : ${Workout.pmg} ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),),
              Text('Secondary Muscle Group : ${Workout.smg} ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),),
              Text('Reps : ${Workout.rep}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),),
              Text('Sets : ${Workout.sets}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),),
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data from one widget to another you have to do two things,

1. Create a constructor of widget having data which it will accept,
2. Pass that data while calling it from another widget.

here is the code which solves your problem:

`workout.dart`

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import './submit.dart';

class Workout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkoutState createState() => _WorkoutState();
}

class _WorkoutState extends State<Workout> {
  String name, sets, rep, pmg, smg;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Create Workouts'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Scaffold(
                    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Exercise Name'),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        name = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration:
                        InputDecoration(hintText: 'Primary Muscle Group'),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        pmg = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration:
                        InputDecoration(hintText: 'Secondary Muscle Group'),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        smg = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Reps'),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        rep = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Sets'),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        sets = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.cyan[200],
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 80.0,
                                    vertical: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Submit',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    //String name, sets, rep, pmg, smg;
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Submit(
                                          name: name,
                                          sets: sets,
                                          rep: rep,
                                          pmg: pmg,
                                          smg: smg,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ]),
                  ))
                ]))),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`submit.dart`

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Submit extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name, sets, rep, pmg, smg;

  const Submit({
    Key key,
    this.name = "",
    this.sets = "",
    this.rep = "",
    this.pmg = "",
    this.smg = "",
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Create Workouts'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Exercise Name : ${name}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Primary Muscle Group : ${pmg} ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Secondary Muscle Group : ${smg} ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Reps : ${rep}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Sets : ${sets}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                  ),
                ]))));
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[New Updated code](https://github.com/TheKetan2/workout_stackoverflow_solution)

Output: [image]

Comment: I really appreciate it man! If possible, do you know how I can center the submit button towards the button of the screen and how to format the text that displays on the next page? For the text, I'm just trying to have it all left aligned and make it look nice.

Comment: Set crossAxisAlignment to center for setting Button in center, to set that button to centre than just add Expanded widget above Button. And in submit file set it to start or space between to set it to start.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to but it doesn't allow me because I have less than 15 reputation. I apologize for that. Also for some reason in Workout.dart lines 110 to 114 it says the named parameter 'name' isn't defined. It says that for all of them. Not sure why.

Comment: Have you made the changes in submit file as shown above?

Comment: Yes, I made all changes but for some reason, I'm getting that error.

Comment: Right now on mobile so can't code, but here is the GitHub repo having your solution, please do check out. And thank you for accepting my answer https://github.com/TheKetan2/stackoverflow_answers

Comment: Thank you and no problem! Still getting that same error and I even tried copy-pasting to see if that would work but doesn't. If you can figure it out later please do comment, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Push your code on GitHub and send me the link, will check out when m coding. Happy Coding, and have a great day ahead.

Comment: Sure, Thank you... https://gitlab.cci.drexel.edu/vnt24/workout-app.git

Comment: it's not letting me log in with my GitLab credentials :/

Comment: Sorry for so many questions but where can I find the updated answer?

Comment: Clone this repo: https://github.com/TheKetan2/workout_stackoverflow_solution then run it. It should work without any error. I am unable to reproduce the errors you quoted, may be some problem with your existing code.

Comment: Everything works now thank you! Quick question.. is it possible to carry that data to a screen but not open that screen? For example once I click submit, I want the data to carry over but instead of opening that page, I want to maybe open the home page instead?

Comment: You can do that, but to persist that data you may want to use backend or state management.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in the navigator.

```
class Workout extends ....> {
  String name;


  Person(this.name);
}

// Navigate to second screen with data
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreenWithData(person: new Person("Vishal"))));
```

Then in the second screen

```
class SecondScreenWithData extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Person data
  final Person person;

  // In the constructor, require a Person
  SecondScreenWithData({Key key, @required this.person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Second Screen With Data"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Display passed data from first screen
            Text("name: ${person.name}"),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Back to previous screen"),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigate back to first screen when tapped!
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```